# stub nodejs promise in chain to return error

Tags: node.js, sinon, chai, es6-promise

I'm new to using `promises` in `nodejs` and also in testing them. I have managed to test the individual modules separately, but when it comes to testing the `chain of promises`, I am having some trouble. I tried following the examples found [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/promises-in-javascript-unit-tests-the-definitive-guide/) and on the `npm` page for [sinon-as-promised](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon-as-promised) but don't seem to managed to control the flow and trigger the error in the first `promise` of the chain.

I am using `mocha`, `chai` and `sinon` for my tests with `sinon-as-promised` and `chai-as-promised`.

I am trying to test this module:

```
'use strict';
var mySQS = require('./modules/sqs/sqs-manager');
var sWebHook = require('./modules/webhooks/shopify/webhooks');
var main = {};
main.manageShopifyWebhook = function (params, callback) {
  sWebHook.verify(params.srcHmac, params.rawBody, params.shopName.split('.myshopify.com')[0], params.productId)
    .then(function(data) {
      var body = {
        "params": {
          "productId": data.productId,
          "shopName": data.shopName
        },
        "job": "call-update-item"
      };
      mySQS.create_Queue(body)
        .then(mySQS.send_Message)
        .then(function(result) {
          callback(null, result);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          callback(error, null);
        });
    });
};

module.exports = main;
```

This is the `sWebHook` module I want to trigger the `reject` callback in the `main` flow:

```
'use strict';

var crypto = require('crypto');
var nconf = require('../../../../config/nconfig');

var webHookManager = {};

webHookManager.verify = function (srcHmac, rawBody, shopName, productId) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    rawBody = new Buffer(rawBody, 'base64');
    var sharedSecret = nconf.get('SHOPIFY_CLIENT_SECRET');
    var digest = crypto.createHmac('SHA256', sharedSecret).update(rawBody).digest('base64');
    console.log('***** CALCULATED DIGEST *****');
    console.log(digest);
    console.log('***** HMAC FROM SHOPIFY *****');
    console.log(srcHmac);
    if (digest !== srcHmac) {
      console.log('Hello');
      var customError = new Error('Unauthorized: HMAC Not Verified');
      reject(customError);
      return false;
    }
    var newEvent = {
      shopName: shopName,
      productId: productId
    };
    console.log('!! WEBHOOK VERIFIED !!');
    resolve(newEvent);
  });
};

module.exports = webHookManager;
```

And these are my tests so far (which do not work):

```
'use strict';

var chai = require('chai');
var sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");
var expect = chai.expect;
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
var sinon = require('sinon');
chai.use(sinonChai);
var proxyquire = require('proxyquire').noCallThru();
var AWS = require('mock-aws');

describe('MAIN', function() {
  require('sinon-as-promised');
  var testedModule,
    sWebHookStub,
    sqsQueueStub,
    sqsSendMsgStub,
    callbackSpy,
    fakeDataObj;

  before(function() {
    sWebHookStub = sinon.stub();
    sqsQueueStub = sinon.stub();
    sqsSendMsgStub = sinon.stub();
    callbackSpy = sinon.spy();
    fakeDataObj = {
      srcHmac: '12345',
      rawBody: 'helloworld',
      shopName: 'mario-test.myshopify.com',
      productId: '6789'
    };
    testedModule = proxyquire('../lib/main', {
      './modules/webhooks/shopify/webhooks': {
        'verify': sWebHookStub
      },
      './modules/sqs/sqs-manager': {
        'create_Queue': sqsQueueStub,
        'send_Message': sqsSendMsgStub
      }
    });
  });

  it('calling shopifyVeriWebhook returns an error', function() {
    var fakeError = new Error('Error verifying webhook');
    sWebHookStub.rejects(fakeError);

    testedModule.manageShopifyWebhook(fakeDataObj, function() {
      callbackSpy.apply(null, arguments);
    });
    expect(callbackSpy).has.been.called.and.calledWith(fakeError, null);
  });
});
```

Comment: So are you asking, how do you validate multiple promise statements in one `it()` and validate that the promise is properly being rejected with a certain Error?

Comment: Yes. So in my example of `main`, I want to force the first promise to call reject with an error and check that the final callback is called with that error.

Answer (score 1):

So, I ended up figuring out how to test chains of promises using `sinon`. For the following `main` module (**Note:** the other modules all return promises):

```
'use strict';

var mySQS = require('./modules/sqs/sqs-manager');
var sWebHook = require('./modules/webhooks/shopify/webhooks');

var main = {};

//@params {object} params
//@params {string} params.srcHmac
//@params {string} params.rawBody
//@params {string} params.shopName - <shop-name.myshopify.com>
//@params {string} params.productId

main.manageShopifyWebhook = function (params) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    sWebHook.verify(params.srcHmac, params.rawBody, params.shopName.split('.myshopify.com')[0], params.productId)
      .then(function(data) {
        var body = {
          "params": {
            "productId": data.productId,
            "shopName": data.shopName
          },
          "job": "call-update-item"
        };
        return mySQS.create_Queue(body);
      })
      .then(mySQS.send_Message)
      .then(resolve)
      .catch(function(err) {
        reject(err);
      });
  });
};

module.exports = main;
```

The secret is to manually `resolve` or `reject` the promises and write the expectation within the callback functions of the `then` or `catch` methods (just as we would do if we were writing tests for async code using `done`). And we then trigger the method we want to test, saving its value to a variable. Like so:

```
'use strict';

var chai = require('chai');
var sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");
var expect = chai.expect;
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
require('sinon-as-promised');
var sinon = require('sinon');
chai.use(sinonChai);
var proxyquire = require('proxyquire').noCallThru();

describe('MAIN', function() {
  require('sinon-as-promised');
  var testedModule,
    sWebHookStub,
    sqsQueueStub,
    sqsSendMsgStub,
    callbackSpy,
    fakeDataObj;

  before(function() {
    sWebHookStub = sinon.stub();
    sqsQueueStub = sinon.stub();
    sqsSendMsgStub = sinon.stub();
    callbackSpy = sinon.spy();
    fakeDataObj = {
      srcHmac: '12345',
      rawBody: 'helloworld',
      shopName: 'mario-test.myshopify.com',
      productId: '6789'
    };
    testedModule = proxyquire('../lib/main', {
      './modules/webhooks/shopify/webhooks': {
        'verify': sWebHookStub
      },
      './modules/sqs/sqs-manager': {
        'create_Queue': sqsQueueStub,
        'send_Message': sqsSendMsgStub
      }
    });
  });

  it('calling shopifyVeriWebhook returns an error when trying to VERIFY WEBHOOK', function() {
    var fakeError = new Error('Error verifying webhook');
    sWebHookStub.rejects(fakeError)().catch(function(error) {
      expect(shopifyWebhook).to.eventually.equal(error);
    });
    var shopifyWebhook = testedModule.manageShopifyWebhook(fakeDataObj);
  });

  it('calling shopifyVeriWebhook returns an error when trying to CREATE SQS QUEUE', function() {
    var fakeBody = {
      "params": {
        "productId": '1234',
        "shopName": 'name'
      },
      "job": "call-update-item"
    };
    var fakeError = new Error('Error creating sqs queue');
    sWebHookStub.resolves(fakeBody)().then(function(result) {
      sqsQueueStub.rejects(fakeError)().catch(function(error) {
        expect(shopifyWebhook).to.eventually.equal(error);
      });
    });
    var shopifyWebhook = testedModule.manageShopifyWebhook(fakeDataObj);
  });

  it('calling shopifyVeriWebhook returns an error when trying to SEND SQS MESSAGE', function() {
    var fakeData = {
      queueUrl: '5678',
      payLoad: '{"message": "Hello World"'
    };
    var fakeBody = {
      "params": {
        "productId": '1234',
        "shopName": 'name'
      },
      "job": "call-update-item"
    };
    var fakeError = new Error('Error sending sqs message');
    sWebHookStub.resolves(fakeBody)().then(function(result) {
      sqsQueueStub.resolves(fakeData)().then(function(result) {
        sqsSendMsgStub.rejects(fakeError)().catch(function(error) {
          expect(shopifyWebhook).to.eventually.equal(error);
        });
      });
    });
    var shopifyWebhook = testedModule.manageShopifyWebhook(fakeDataObj);
  });

  it('calling shopifyVeriWebhook is SUCCESSFUL', function() {
    var fakeData = {
      queueUrl: '5678',
      payLoad: '{"message": "Hello World"'
    };
    var fakeBody = {
      "params": {
        "productId": '1234',
        "shopName": 'name'
      },
      "job": "call-update-item"
    };
    var fakeResponse = {
      'message': 'success'
    };
    sWebHookStub.resolves(fakeBody)().then(function(result) {
      sqsQueueStub.resolves(fakeData)().then(function(result) {
        sqsSendMsgStub.resolves(fakeResponse)().then(function(result) {
          expect(shopifyWebhook).to.eventually.equal(result);
        });
      });
    });
    var shopifyWebhook = testedModule.manageShopifyWebhook(fakeDataObj);
  });
});
```

**Bonus sample** - I needed to run my code on `aws lambda`, and therefore needed to have a final callback. So I had the main entry point to my code in a file called `lambda.js`:

```
'use strict';

var main = require('./lib/main');

//Verifies shopify webhooks
//@params {object} event
//@params {string} event.srcHmac
//@params {string} event.rawBody
//@params {string} event.shopName - <shop-name.myshopify.com>
//@params {string} event.productId
exports.shopifyVerifyWebHook = function (event, context, callback) {
  console.log('---- EVENT ----');
  console.log(event);
  main.manageShopifyWebhook(event)
    .then(function(result) {
      callback(null, result);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      callback(err, null);
    });
};
```

And for this I needed to control the result of the promises and make sure the callback was called with either an `error` or a `success` message.
The premiss is the same.

```
describe('LAMBDA', function() {
  var testedModule,
    mainShopStub,
    callbackSpy,
    mainModule,
    fakeEvent;

  before(function() {
    callbackSpy = sinon.spy();
    fakeEvent = {
      srcHmac: '12345',
      rawBody: 'helloworld',
      shopName: 'mario-test.myshopify.com',
      productId: '6789'
    };
    testedModule = require('../lambda');
    mainModule = require('../lib/main');
    mainShopStub = sinon.stub(mainModule, 'manageShopifyWebhook');
  });

  after(function() {
    mainShopStub.restore();
  });

  it('calling shopifyVerifyWebHook returns an error', function() {
    var fakeError = new Error('Error running lambda');
    mainShopStub.rejects(fakeError);
    mainShopStub().catch(function (error) {
      expect(callbackSpy).has.been.called.and.calledWith(error, null);
    });

    testedModule.shopifyVerifyWebHook(fakeEvent, {}, function() {
      callbackSpy.apply(null, arguments);
    });
  });

  it('calling shopifyVerifyWebHook return a data object', function() {
    var fakeObj = {message: 'success'};
    mainShopStub.resolves(fakeObj);
    mainShopStub().then(function (result) {
      expect(callbackSpy).has.been.called.and.calledWith(null, result);
    });

    testedModule.shopifyVerifyWebHook(fakeEvent, {}, function() {
      expected.resolves(fakeObj);
      callbackSpy.apply(null, arguments);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Before getting into how to test multiple promises and validating errors, there is a much larger problem with your code.

`manageShopifyWebhook()` is constructed using an anti-pattern of promises which is, you're using a callback structure to return your promise value instead of returning your promise directly. If you do this, you're taking away a large benefit of promises, direct chain for error handling. Furthermore, you won't be able to use `sinon-as-promised` and `chai-as-promised` since they expect a `Promise`/`thenable` to be returned.

However, this is a rather quick fix in your code, by simply returning the promise created by `sWebHook.verify()`:

```
main.manageShopifyWebhook = function (params) {
  // Return the promise directly
  // the final return will be returned to the original caller of manageShopifyWebhook
  return sWebHook.verify(params.srcHmac, params.rawBody, params.shopName.split('.myshopify.com')[0], params.productId)
    .then(function(data) {
      var body = {
        "params": {
          "productId": data.productId,
          "shopName": data.shopName
        },
        "job": "call-update-item"
      };
      return mySQS.create_Queue(body);
    })
      .then(mySQS.send_Message)
      .then(function(result) {
        return result;
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        // In reality you can let error propagate out here 
        // if you don't need to do anything special with it and let 
        // the promise just return the error directly
        // I've only done this so we can return 'Error Verifying Webhook' as an error from the promise returned by manageShopifyWebhook()
        return Promise.reject(new Error('Error verifying webook'));      
      });
  });
};
```

Now that `manageShopfiyWebhook()` is returning a promise, you can use the two `as-promised` test libraries.

For `chai-as-promised` you need to convert your `expect()` to look for a promise using the chain `eventually` and then you can use `rejectedWith()` to validate the Error/Error Message.

To validate multiple promises tests you can use `Promise.all()` and pass in all your promise returning assertions and return the outcome of `Promise.all()` to your mocha `it()`.

I don't use `sinon` but the above should've given you enough direction to figure out how to use this pattern with `sinon-as-promised` as well since it will work for any Promise returning testing library.

```
it('calling shopifyVeriWebhook returns an error', function() {
  var fakeError = new Error('Error verifying webhook');
  let shopifyWebhook = testedModule.manageShopifyWebhook(fakeDataObj);

  return Promise.all([
    expect(shopifyWebhook).to.eventually.be.rejectedWith(fakeError);
  ]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks peteb. One question though. If you're returning a promise in `catch`, shouldn't this happen as well before where you have `return result`?

Comment: They both return a Promise because you're returning the Promise created by `sWebHook.verify()`. In the `then()` the `return result` automatically is resolved, this translates to a "success" or rather that there was no failure. The value returned in `catch()` is a rejection, notice `return Promise.reject()`, it signals to the caller of `manageShopifyWebhook()` that something happened and that the function wasn't successful.

Comment: As it is now, could I pass the error to the caller of `manageShopifyWebhook()`?

Comment: @hyprstack like I said, I don't use sinon so I can't say for sure, however you could just pass in bad parameters which would result in an error.

Comment: But by passing in bad parameters I can only cause the first function in the chain to fail. I need to be able to determine the type of result each promise will return. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: Thats not how promises work, if any of them reject, it will skip all `then()` functions and jump right to the nearest `catch()` so it will reject.